# macos - installing xcode 9.2 on macOS 10.13

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

and i saw the xcode 9.2 is run on macOS 10.12.6 and i have macOS 10.13 
so i downloaded xcode 9.2.
and while installing i will get this error

[image]

so how can i fix this error?
or if is not running on my macOS version is there any trick to install that?

Comment: Update 1013 to it's latest version and then install Xcode 9.3 from AppStore on Mac.

Comment: @Nitish theres no another way? i'm in Iran and we have slow internet here so it's kind of difficult to download macOS update and then Xcode :(

Comment: Download Xcode 9.2 - https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?name=Xcode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try installing Xcode 9.3 from the Appstore, here is the Appstore link:

https://itunes.apple.com/mx/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

Comment: This should really be a comment

Comment: @luk2302 : Ditto

Comment: appstore says my macOS is old so i downloaded xcode from another website

Comment: @AmirTvs what website are you trying to download it from?

Comment: @PabloMarrufo it is and iranian website for mac apps. macneed.ir

Comment: @luk2302 thanks for the suggest, I'll take it into account for the next time. I was deleting my answer and commenting it, when he replied. :/

Comment: @AmirTvs Download it from the apple developer website. You could get malware from that site. In the following url you can download any version of Xcode you need. https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: @PabloMarrufo theres no another way? i have slow internet connection so it's kind of difficult to download 5g again

Comment: @AmirTvs I wouldn't risk for getting malware on my computer because of my internet connection